# Program not giving hex value?

Tags: c, math, binary, char, hex

My program is giving the right value for Decimal but I'm using char to gt values for Hex

Can someone see my code and tell me why my Output is simply a "?" (Attached my output as image)

I know you can add char values.

Here is my code. Please do not try to change my entire code saying what I'm doing is "the longer way".

Note I am only testing HexVal1 for now as it only takes in account first 4 bits.

What the program is supposed to do is take first 4 bits of binary and throw out a hex character.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int bit1,bit2,bit3,bit4,bit5,bit6,bit7,bit8;
    int dec1,dec2,dec3,dec4,dec5,dec6,dec7,dec8;
    char hex1,hex2,hex3,hex4,hex5,hex6,hex7,hex8;
    int BinVal;
    char HexVal1;
    char HexVal2;

    printf("Please enter the first bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit1);
    printf("Please enter the second bi(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit2);  
    printf("Please enter the third bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit3);  
    printf("Please enter the fourth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit4);  
    printf("Please enter the fifth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit5);  
    printf("Please enter the sixth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit6);  
    printf("Please enter the seventh bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit7);
    printf("Please enter the eigth bit:(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit8);


    if(bit1==1){
        dec1=1;
        hex1='1';
        }

    else{
    dec1=0;
    hex1='0';
    }

        if(bit2==1){
        dec2=2;
        hex2='2';
        }

    else{
    dec2=0;
    hex2='0';
    }

        if(bit3==1){
        dec3=4;
        hex3='4';
        }

    else{
    dec3=0;
    hex3='0';
    }

        if(bit4==1){
        dec4=8;
        hex4='8';
        }

    else{
    dec4=0;
    hex4='0';
    }

        if(bit5==1){
        dec5=16;
        hex5='16';
        }

    else{
    dec5=0;
    hex5='0';
    }

        if(bit6==1){
        dec6=32;
        hex6='32';
        }

    else{
    dec6=0;
    hex6='0';
    }

        if(bit7==1){
        dec7=64;
        hex7='64';
        }

    else{
    dec7=0;
    hex7='0';
    }

        if(bit8==1){
        dec8=128;
        hex8='128';
        }

    else{
    dec8=0;
    hex8='0';   
       }






    BinVal=dec1+dec2+dec3+dec4+dec5+dec6+dec7+dec8;
    printf("Binary value for your decimal number is %d",BinVal);

    HexVal1=sizeof(hex1)+sizeof(hex2)+sizeof(hex3)+sizeof(hex4);

    if(HexVal1==15){
        HexVal1='F';
    }

    else if (HexVal1==14){
     HexVal1='E';
    }

    else if (HexVal1==13){

    HexVal1='D';
    }

    else if(HexVal1==12){

    HexVal1='C';
    }

    else if(HexVal1==11){

    HexVal1='B';
    }

    else if(HexVal1==10){
    HexVal1='A';
    }


    printf("\nHex Val for first 4 bits is %c", HexVal1);

    return 0;

}
```

The Output is as below

```
Please enter the first bit(0 or 1): 1
Please enter the second bi(0 or 1): 0
Please enter the third bit(0 or 1): 0
Please enter the fourth bit(0 or 1): 1
Please enter the fifth bit(0 or 1): 1
Please enter the sixth bit(0 or 1): 1
Please enter the seventh bit(0 or 1): 1
Please enter the eigth bit:(0 or 1): 1
Binary value for your decimal number is 249
Hex Val for first 4 bits is
```

Comment: why are you doing this: `HexVal1=sizeof(hex1)+sizeof(hex2)+sizeof(hex3)+sizeof(hex4);`

Comment: Do you know what `sizeof` does? `hex8='128'` it's  not legal, `hex8` can hold only a single character, `'128'` is a multi-character character constant

Comment: Check the hyperlink to the image I've posted, you will see what the program is supposed to do

Comment: @MuhammadShaeelAbbas please don't post pictures of output, copy & paste the output in your question!

Comment: @Pablo Done! :))

Comment: Your code makes no sense to me, specially the whole "hex" part. This whole line `HexVal1=sizeof(hex1)+sizeof(hex2)+sizeof(hex3)+sizeof(hex4);` makes absolutely no sense, I don't even understand what is the logic behind this.

Comment: `hex8 = '128'` _is_ legal, @Pablo; it is just implementation defined.  The multicharacter constant has an integer value that is implementation defined, and the result of assigning that to `hex8` is therefore implementation defined.  You can assign a large integer to a `char` and the significant bits get truncated, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the clarification, gcc does indeed not give you an error with `char x = '128'` but only a warning.

Comment: If your code is printing weird characters, it's because you're trying (but failing) to create character values in some tricky, low-level way -- which, looking at this convoluted code, isn't surprising. Per your request, I won't try to change it, but I will say: it is probably too long and complicated and error-prone for you to debug, and it is *definitely* too long for me to debug.  You have got to find a better way to do this.

Comment: If you have an integer and you want to print it out in decimal and hex, just use `printf` with `%d` and `%x`.  If you want to learn how to manipulate individual bits and bytes, and do "hexadecimal conversion" yourself, please do it using loops, and shifts and masks, or multiplication and division.  See [question 20.10](http://c-faq.com/misc/hexio.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/) (and [this footnote](http://c-faq.com/misc/btod.html)) for hints.

Comment: When you've got *8 separate cases*, one for *every bit*, it's just way too easy to have a subtle bug that affects only one bit -- a bug that ought to be impossible.

Comment: I did it MY way. It's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Have accepted the right answer. Feel free to have a look at their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to rewrite the whole thing. It can be valuable to do things "the long way" as a learning exercise. You can optimize later. But, your code doesn't work because of several misunderstandings. Have a look at these topics:

- [Integer
  Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Integer-Types) (`char` is basically just an 8-bit integer)
- [Character constants](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Character-Constants) (how to use those single-quotes)
- [sizeof](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-sizeof-Operator) (it doesn't do what you think it does)

So, for the minimal change to get your code working, you don't want to be assigning those single-quoted values to your "hex" variables at all; you just want to be assigning unquoted numerical values. (Also, you should at least use `unsigned char` to make sure they can hold a value of 128.)

```
unsigned char hex1,... /* etc. */
```

and

```
hex8=128;
```

And then you can just add them up:

```
unsigned char HexVal1, HexVal2;
HexVal1 = hex1 + hex2 + hex3 + hex4;
HexVal2 = (hex5 + hex6 + hex7 + hex8) / 16;
```

This will give HexVal1 and HexVal2 the range 0 to 15 that you are expecting. (Unlike your original code in which HexVal1 always has a value of 4!)

Then, your conversion at the end is also problematic. You are changing the numerical values 10-15 into the characters 'A'-'F', which is fine... but you have to convert the lower values, too! `4` is not the same value as `'4'`. (And this is why your program outputs a question mark. HexVal1 contains the value 4, which is not a printable character. See the [ASCII character set](https://www.asciitable.com/).)

There are many, many things you can do to further improve upon that, but if you make those minimal fixes, your code should work.

Comment: You are truely a great helping hand and you pointed out where I was wrong. The only thing for me to figure out is that the conversions. If my hex value is less than 10 it will give out a Question Mark.

If it's 10 it will give A

I'm still thinking about it!

Comment: Glad to help! Do you mean, how to convert the values 0-9 into their correct values? Well, there's a couple ways. You could do it the same as you did with 10-15. For example: `if (HexVal1==9) { HexVal1 = '9'; }`. Hopefully you get the difference between `9` and `'9'`. If not, check out the [ASCII character set](https://www.asciitable.com/). The first column on the left are the unprintable characters, including 0-15. The digits `'0'` - `'9'` are located in the bottom half of the second column, and you'll notice their **_numerical_** values are actually 48-57. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's probably easier to think about if you look at letters instead. `'A'` - `'F'` are located at the top of column three, and their numerical values are actually 65-70. Then you just have to realize that `'0'` - `'9'` are just characters -- graphically rendered shapes -- no different from a letter or a punctuation mark. Those characters have numerical representations just like any other character does.

Comment: Also, if you agree I answered your question correctly, please accept my answer.  :-)

Comment: I will definitely accept your answer. I can now also represent 0 to 9 in Hex for HexVal1, the only issue I'm having is that HexVal2 is represented in ASCII by symbols. The code I literally copy pasted and amended (Replaced HexVal1 with HexVal2 etc etc)

Do you think this is a syntax error I'm having that I can't find?

Comment: No its okay actually,  I just forgot to replace hex5 with 1, hex6 with 2, hex7 with 4, hex8 with 8. They still had the old values, so nevermind.

Your answer has been accepted my friend. May you prosper! Thank you!